# Remove String Between Substring from RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

I write this code for remove string from 'a' to 'c'

```
var str = "abcbbabbabcd";
var re = new RegExp("a.*?c","gi");
str = str.replace(re,"");
console.log(str);
```

The result in console is "bbd"

But the result that right for me is "bbabbd"

Can I use Regular Expression for this Problem ?

Thank for help.

Comment: This does correct remove strings from 'a' to 'c'. Perhaps you rather mean strings that go from 'a' to 'c' but excluding 'a'? If that is so please edit the question so it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a(?:(?!a).)*c
```

Use a `lookahead` based regex.See demo.`.*?` will consume `a` as well after first `a`.To stop it use a `lookahead`.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/34

EDIT:

```
a[^a]*c
```

You can actually use `negated character class` as you have only 1 character.

Comment: Use negated character class if it's a single character.

Answer (score 1):

The `g` means it's a global regexp, meaning it picks up both the `abc` and `abbabc` in the string. So this does properly remove the items from `a..c`. It seems you saw only two `abc` and missed the `abbabc`. The result `bbd` is actually correct as it does indeed *"remove string from 'a' to 'c'"*.

> <strike>`abc`</strike>`bb`<strike>`abbabc`</strike>`d => bbd`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your regex to **[`a[^ac]*?c`](https://regex101.com/r/kJ7vQ5/1)** , this will avoid character `a` and `c` between `a` and `c`

```js
var str = "abcbbabbabcd";
var re = new RegExp("a[^ac]*?c","gi");
str = str.replace(re,"");
console.log(str);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way.

```
var str = "abcbbabbabcd";
var str= str.replace(/abc/g, ""); 
console.log(str);
```